# Iterating over a table type using T-SQL inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have passed an array of int values to a stored procedure as table type. Based on the individual values, I have to do some operations in the database by iterating over the table type values.

I'd be grateful if someone could shed some light on this matter. I am considering a cursor as only the last option. Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Please find the sample SP code below,

```
SubIds Type,
DateCreated DateTime,

Declare Id Int
//
Have to iterate here to get one id at a time from SubIds

Set Id = // have to get from the SubIds based on the iteration

// With the Id I have to so series of operations like 
// retrieving some values, compare, calculate and insert the 
// calculated values in some table

// End of iteration
```

Thanks

Comment: you can treat table type as any other table(only reads),so you can use join

Comment: Please post some sample code. What exactly do you want to do with the values? search on them? join on them? write them?

Comment: Nick, I have edited the OP for the sample code. Pardon me for the highlevel description.

Comment: You can probably do what you want to do using a _set based solution_. A set based solution is generally superior in every way to a cursor based solution. I suggest you use this as an opportunity to learn how to do things properly (set based) in a database rather than procedurally (cursor based). If you can explain in more detail what you want to do maybe we can help.